# Appium iOS Simulator Setup error

Tags: ios, testing, selenium, automated-tests, appium

I have a .app file that I copied to my mac in a local directory (Ex: /appium/test.app) and I pointed appium to the .app file. I'm getting the following error when running in the simulator:

```
Could not save new Info.plist
Error: ENOTDIR, not a directory
```

Can any one resolve my issue? Correct me if i am doing any fundamental wrong.

Comment: Not really an answer but more a related issue. I see this error if I use the 'locationServicesAuthorized' capability with an 'app' capability that is an IPA or a zip. This is known issue https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/3769

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten that error if I start the Appium server via the Mac App and point it at an .app directory in the Settings of the app.

**[You should try running Appium from the command line.](http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.1.0/?ruby#quick-start)**